# GTK stock items - change label language

Tags: python, gtk, label, stock

I'm using Windows and the language settings are set to German. When i'm using for example Stock Buttons with pygtk, the label is always in German, however i want it in English! 
So i want to display all labels in English even if the os language is set to a different language.

I have no idea how to get this work and couldn't find any solution! 
Thank you for helping me.

Comment: STOCK_* is deprecated since 3.x - you should use the proper names of the icons instead (not the path http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html#names https://docs.google.com/document/d/1KCVPoYQBqMbDP11tHPpjW6uaEHrvLUmcDPqKAppCY8o/pub)